# Will lwc cacheable=true be able to do dml in future methods

Tags: lightning-web-components

In Lwc's apex controller, if a method is marked as cacheable=true, it is not allowed to do DML statements directly, which will throw too many DML statement error.

I tried a walkaround with this to use future method to do the dml. No error has been seen afterwards. However, when I query the database afterwards I don't see the DML operation been done.

I am wondering is it possible to do DML in cacheable=true methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, future methods are a separate transaction, and are not subject to the limits of cacheable=true methods. Note that you should avoid DML in such a method, because there is no guarantee the method will be called every time (e.g. if a response is already in the cache). However, this does technically work. I actually wrote a script to prove it, and it does work.

Comment: Does that mean it will work but will not be working every time? Is it possible to have an approach that can utilise the performance of cacheable=true and still be able to do dml of logs in exception scenarios?

Comment: @LanceShi If you're just logging something, that would be fine; after all, the Apex method that would log such an exception wouldn't run if its response were already cached. If you're not seeing any activity on the server, that's just the cache doing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, as of October 2020, @AuraEnabled (Cacheable = true) methods CAN publish platform events, which can be used to fire a subsequent trigger to execute DML code. Note that the events must be defined as "Publish Immediate", and not "Publish after commit".

Overview of Platform Event Publish Behaviors:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics/platform_events_define_publish